# Why does Heathcliff (Kayaba) smile at the end in episode 14?

Tags: sword-art-online

In episode 14 of SAO, at the 14th minute mark:

> Kirito kills Kayaba.  He did not try to stop Kirito, and died smiling. Was he waiting to be killed by Kirito?

Did Kayaba expect it?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your question--what episode/chapter it occured in, etc.? Additionally, your title seems to be asking a different question from the body of your text, so please clarify what you want answered.

Comment: @kuwaly I am specifically talking about episode 14, minute 14. He does not look surprised when Kirito is revived, and does not block Kirito from killing him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [SAO Wiki](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Kayaba_Akihiko#cite_ref-popularitycontest_8-6):

> The happiest moment to Akihiko during SAO was when Kirito saw through his true identity on the 75th floor, as Akihiko then realized that he (Akihiko) was nothing more than another player.

<sub>- Q&A session in the third popularity contest held by Kawahara Reki as Kunori Fumio, 2005</sub>

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly it's never said. But it's probably to do with the fact the Kirito defied the system, as Kayaba does mention something similar in the final episode of Season 1.

Answer (score 0):

Kayaba is smiling thruout his battle with Kirito, during one part he smiles because he knows Kirito is beaten. He only frowns in displeasure of Kirito's lack of fighting spirit after Asuna dies.

Kayaba is smiling because it is an amusing turn of event for a story. He is not looking at this normally because he has already accepted his death and knows this is the best time to end this story.

I say this because Kayaba originally excused his involvement with the game as a player by saying it would be a nice twist if the #1 player becomes the tragic last boss.

Answer (score -2):

Kayaba had his own adventure aswell. Full of love, and heartbreak.

Kayaba loved his wife, but was so driven to make his dream of the steel castle real that he ruined his marriage.

Kayaba met someone in game who made him happy named Minami, and she knew from the start about Heathcliff being Kayaba, and she saw beauty in his world, but she was killed in an off screen boss fight.

So when he smiles it's because not only did he want to die, but he saw how fitting it is for his own game to kill both his marriages, and himself.

Comment: Kayaba never had a wife but he had a love interest who took care of his body while he was in the game and the only Minami i can find any mention of is the Manga's artist Minami Juusei